# Jung Graph visualization: vertices displaying like christmas light

Tags: graph, jung

Please, help needed. I am trying to visualize a graph with jung but the vertices keeps moving about and changing color randomly. What I want to achieve is to display some vertices with a particular color (like having vertices with clusters distinguished by color) and then go on to visualize a path between two vertices of interest. The number of vertices are over 500. I am new to jung and to achieve this task, I have tried to modify a code I got from a thread on this forum. The code I am working with is shown below

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.ISOMLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.RenderContext;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.DefaultModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.ModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.Renderer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.transform.shape.GraphicsDecorator;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;

public class graphMainHelp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparseGraph graph = new SparseGraph();
    String[] vertices = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        graph.addVertex((String) vertices[i]);
    }

    graph.addEdge(1, "J", "A");
    graph.addEdge(2, "A", "C");
    graph.addEdge(3, "B", "A");
    graph.addEdge(4, "B", "J");
    graph.addEdge(5, "I", "E");
    graph.addEdge(6, "B", "F");
    graph.addEdge(7, "C", "A");
    graph.addEdge(8, "G", "E");
    graph.addEdge(9, "G", "F");
    graph.addEdge(10, "H", "B");
    graph.addEdge(11, "G", "C");
    graph.addEdge(12, "E", "G");
    graph.addEdge(13, "I", "B");
    graph.addEdge(14, "F", "J");
    graph.addEdge(15, "F", "E");


    if (graph.getVertexCount() != 0 || graph.getEdgeCount() != 0) {
        Layout<String, String> layout = new ISOMLayout<String, String>(graph);
        layout.setSize(new Dimension(700, 700));

        VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<String, String>(layout);



        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new Transformer<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public String transform(String arg0) {
                return arg0;
            }
        });

        vv.getRenderer().setVertexRenderer(new MyRenderer());


         final DefaultModalGraphMouse<String, Number> graphMouse = new
         DefaultModalGraphMouse<String, Number>();
         graphMouse.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);
         vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }// close main method    


}

static class MyRenderer implements Renderer.Vertex<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void paintVertex(RenderContext<String, String> rc, Layout<String, String> layout, String vertex) {
        GraphicsDecorator graphicsContext = rc.getGraphicsContext();
        Point2D center = layout.transform(vertex);

        Shape shape = null;
        Color color = null;

        shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(center.getX() - 10, center.getY() - 10, 20, 20);
        Random random = new Random();
        int r = random.nextInt(256);  
        int g = random.nextInt(200);
        int b = random.nextInt(250);

        color = new Color(r, g, b);
        graphicsContext.setPaint(color);
        graphicsContext.fill(shape);

    }
}//close static class
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The vertices are changing color because you told them to: every time you render a vertex you are giving it a new random color to paint it.  I don't understand why you're using a custom renderer at all, really.  If you want to specify shape or color other than the default, look at [PluggableRendererContext](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/PluggableRenderContext.html) and the associated demo.

There are a number of demos in the JUNG download itself; I recommend that you take a look at them rather than starting with samples on StackOverflow.

Comment: I will check out the demos as you suggested. I appreciate your quick response.